# How to use the guided missile unlock for tanks?

Tags: battlefield-3

I recently unlocked the guided missile for tanks. The first round using it was a blast. I ended up killing a total of 36 helicopters, tanks and vehicles.

However the second round (and every round since), was terrible. The little lock-on symbol that previously appeared when I pointed at a vehicle, doesn't show anymore. Which means I can't fire.

So I'm puzzled as to why it worked brilliantly that first round, but hasn't worked since.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guided shell is a perk that requires teamwork to use effectively (or at all). You need a teammate using a laser designation device (SOFLAM, CITV station (last tank unlock), laser painter (on jets and choppers)) before you will be able to lock on to *anything* in the air or out of line of sight. You can lock onto land vehicles in line of sight.

Until that point, it is just a lovely piece of useless machinery.

Comment: You should be able to lock onto ground vehicles without laser designation, but this is correct for air vehicles.

Answer (score 9):

In your first round, some one on your team must have been laser designating your opponents.  That is the only way the guided missile unlock can target air vehicles.

**Air targets must be laser designated before you can target them with the guided shell perk.**

Answer (score 1):

In all fairness, the guides missile is pretty useless anyway.
   Hardly anyone ever uses a SOFLAM, and when they do the missile takes so damn long to get to the target that %90  of the time the enemy vehicle has either deployed smoke, or has moved out of sight of the designator anyway, and as it takes 2 missiles to even disable the sodding tanks, getting 2/3 consecutive hits is nigh on impossible.